# castle activerecord lazy get id

Tags: lazy-loading, castle-activerecord

I have these two classes

```
[ActiveRecord("Customers", Lazy=true)]
public class Customer : ActiveRecordBase<Customer>
{
    [PrimaryKey(PrimaryKeyType.Identity, Access = PropertyAccess.AutomaticProperty)]
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }

    [Property]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [HasMany(Lazy = true)]
    public virtual IList<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

[ActiveRecord("Orders", Lazy=true)]
public class Order : ActiveRecordBase<Order>
{
    [PrimaryKey(PrimaryKeyType.Identity, Access = PropertyAccess.AutomaticProperty)]
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }

    [Property]
    public virtual string Product { get; set; }

   [BelongsTo(Lazy = FetchWhen.OnInvoke)]
   public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

I want to select all orders and foreach of them, get the id of the customer.
So I do this:

```
using (new SessionScope())
{
   var orders = Order.FindAll();
   foreach (var o in orders)
   {
      int id = o.Customer.Id;
   }
}
```

It works, but it creates a SELECT phrase for each call to o.Customer.Id. 
Now, the Order already has the Id of the customer, so how can I get it without revisiting the database??

Answer (score 0):

the following code should allow you to get the id (but I couldn't test it at the moment):

```
int id = (int)((INHibernateProxy)order.Customer).HibernateLazyInitializer.Identifier;
```

Greetings

Juy Juka